# Angular js getting error while updating date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form to submit data. I have one Date field in that form. All is working fine. But when i try to retrieve data to update including date. i get error "ngModel:datefmt". 
I have tried converting date formats in database YY-mm-dd and dd-mm-yy. 
I have tried converting date formats in JavaScript to yy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yy.
I am using input type ="date".

Comment: Please provide some working or non working code samples so that we can help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the date  as string hence you are getting the error you need to convert it to date object ,

```
$scope.dateField = new Date(date_string);
```

I would recommend to use a directive for this to use it in the input element.

```
<input convert-date type="date" ng-model="dateField">

app.directive('convertDate', function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {ngModel : '='},
    link: function (scope) {
        if (scope.ngModel)
        {
         scope.ngModel = new Date(scope.ngModel);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You are right ! Instead of using directive I  used toString() to convert database date and It worked for me. Thank you !!